# Modal with embedded pdf

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, simplemodal

I am trying to put a modal on a website I am making that has an embedded PDF.

The pdf shows up really small. I did not write this code from scratch. I found it on another site. Can anyone help?

I'm using the Zurb Foundation framework, FYI.

https://jsfiddle.net/8ryeqfbc/

HTML----

```
<section class="modal">
            <div class="wrap row small-up-1 medium-up-1">
                <div class="special column"><h3>Modal</h3>
                    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
                        <button id="myBtn">View Full Menu</button>

                        <!-- The Modal -->
                        <div id="myModal" class="modal">

                        <!-- Modal content -->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <span class="close">x</span>
                            <iframe src="pdf.pdf"></iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>             
            </div>
    </section>
```

Javascript ---

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

CSS-----

```
* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 500px; /* Full width */
    height: 500px; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 95%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style the `iframe` to have it fill the modal box.

```
.modal-content iframe {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```